# When Hazelcast will dynamically add a new node?

Tags: hazelcast

When hazelcast will add a new node to a cluster. If a new node is added it will be functioning in different port number. So If we have to access the data from that node whether we have to add its ip address and port number in the client side?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't have to this. 
In client side,It is enough to connect 1 member. Everytime  client connects 1 node. And get cluster information from that node.

Providing more member info ensure that: when node that has a client connection crashes, client tries to connect other members that provided in its configuration.